# error installing amdgpupro 18.50 driver on linux mint 19.1

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, amd-graphics, amd, ati

Previously installed amd-gpu-pro and solved the problem with the fact that the firewood on Ubuntu was not installed on my Mint, giving an error about the wrong OS. With that question, I figured it out. In amd-gpu-pro install, I changed OS check from Ubuntu to LinuxMint in the “launcher”. After these manipulations, the download went, but the problem is as follows: 
When installing drivers, an error occurs:

```
    Errors occurred while processing the following packages:
     /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-1aU6FT/00-amdgpu-core_18.50-756341_all.deb 
     E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

When I try to install again, I get this:

```
mesa-amdgpu-vdpau-drivers: Depends: amdgpu-core but it will not be installed
 wsa-amdgpu: Depends: amdgpu-core but it will not be installed
 wsa-amdgpu: i386: Depends: amdgpu-core: i386
 xserver-xorg-amdgpu-video-amdgpu: Depends: amdgpu-core but it will not be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try running “apt --fix-broken install” without specifying the package name, (or find another solution).
```

And if you run `sudo apt-get --fix-broken install` , then I get the same as when you first install:

```
Errors occurred while processing the following packages:
 /var/opt/amdgpu-pro-local/./amdgpu-core_18.50-756341_all.deb
E: Sub-process / usr / bin / dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution on one of the forums.
First you need to clear all amd packages in the synaptic manager.
Next: Use this command to open it: `xed admin:///etc/os-release`

```
NAME="Linux Mint"
VERSION="19 (Tara)"
ID=linuxmint
ID_LIKE=ubuntu
PRETTY_NAME="Linux Mint 19"
VERSION_ID="19"
HOME_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://forums.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://linuxmint-troubleshooting-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.linuxmint.com/"
VERSION_CODENAME=tara
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

Change the word linuxmint to ubuntu in line 3 and change the number 19 to 18.04 in line 6. After the installation, you can change these back. The amdgpu-pro-install script does not have to be edited.
 Use the command `./amdgpu-pro-install`